# Sugesstion for a multilingual site using Joomla

Tags: php, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I want to create a multilingual site using Joomla. The site will be in English and Hindi. Along with the static pages the Administrator should be able to post his research may be as a blog and a registered member can read the post and add his comments and/or questions. The administrator will then reply the comment and/or the question.

I'm new to Joomla and could not figure out how to start with this project. I must use all the extensions which are free to use. Is there any option for this or Should I create my own blogging system ? I need to set up donation functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

My advise will be to use one of this component to set up the admin blog : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog

And here is a module for the donation : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/donations

Do not create your own blogging system, you can easly achieve your project with Joomla!

Comment: I checked the first one and found it is a paid extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using K2 as a replacement for the built in Joomla articles and categories. It has a ton of features that would allow you to make a blog and manage all of your other content pages as well all within one component. It is also a lot more flexible than a component that is specifically for blogging so you can set it up to suite your needs.

You will probably want to install a multilingual component as well. For 1.7/2.5 you will need to use FaLang unless you want to wait for JoomFish to come out for 2.5.

K2 - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/8061

FaLang - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/18210

JoomFish - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/460

Comment: K2 extension is free and also I found it is easy to use. But still I'm fighting with some things, like - create list of excerpts with read more link on a single page.

Comment: That is the same as the Joomla blog view. You can achieve that by creating a menu link to K2 categories.